# Exception replaying log : Solr

Tags: solr

Solr was working perfectly until suddenly as soon as I run it, an exception is thrown

the exception is :

```
WARNING: REPLAY_ERR: Exception replaying log

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.lucene.queries.function.FunctionValues.longVal(FunctionValues.java:46)
    at org.apache.solr.update.VersionInfo.getVersionFromIndex(VersionInfo.java:201)
    at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.lookupVersion(UpdateLog.java:711)
    at org.apache.solr.update.VersionInfo.lookupVersion(VersionInfo.java:184)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:571)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:350)
    at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog$LogReplayer.doReplay(UpdateLog.java:1268)
    at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog$LogReplayer.run(UpdateLog.java:1159)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

after digging in this issue i found that the class `FunctionValues` did Not implement the following functions

```
public float floatVal(int doc) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
public int intVal(int doc) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
public long longVal(int doc) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
...
```

while in the [documentation](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repo1.maven.org%24maven2@org.apache.lucene%24lucene-queries@4.0.0@org%24apache%24lucene%24queries%24function@FunctionValues@longVal%28int%29&start=0&type=method&k=u) there is nothing about this,

How it was working, and what I'm missing to fix this issue?

Comment: Please mention the version of Solr. If it is 4.0, try upgrading to 4.1

Comment: Sir, its actually 4.1, do you think that they have an issue with there code?

Comment: It is happening to me with version 4.2.0 too

Answer (score 0):

In the schema.xml, what is your _version_ field type? We ran into this and our _version_ field type was set to string and had to be changed to slong.

This only manifested itself when we started using sharding and/or replicating. When it was a single core on a single node, there was no issue at all.

**The wrong way**

```
<field name="_version_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

**The way that worked**

```
<field name="_version_" type="slong" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction -

The type should be "long". It solves the problem.